# Java service transaction practice

Tags: java, spring, transactional

We use to define transaction using @Transactional annotation or else way to défine transactions. 
We also use to define a transaction on a service or specificaly on its methods.

Recently, a colleague suggested no to set transaction on services but on the caller (remote controller for angular, batch, IHM controller like jsf...).
I found this approach interestings.

What do you think about this ?

Comment: Making the layer above the service layer transactional is a bad idea imho. This basically means you are making your transactions dependent on the web (in your case) not sure if that is something you want.

Comment: Be very careful expanding transaction scope.  In most RDBMS's I've worked with, certain types of locks are held for the duration of a transaction, so your lock boundaries are defined by transaction boundaries.  By making a transaction broader, you hold locks longer, which limits concurrency.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need both. Services should be transactional, or at least `SUPPORTS` for reads / selects. But, in the web controller or other top-level layer you *also* need transactions if you call more than one service.

Note, however, that if you controllers are concrete classes, you are going to need to use AOP or other proxy mechanisms to wrap functions in a transactional layer. The other option is to just autowire in a `TransactionTemplate` into your controllers and do TX management manually where you need it.

Obviously the TX template approach means you have to be careful to actually use it when needed. With the proxy approach you can just make every controller function transactional. But the overhead may be more than you want if there are only a few functions that make more than one service call.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers. It seems that @Transactional position is not so obvious